# Stomp Session Handler: once connection established the handler is not notified in afterConnected() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm trying to build websocket connection with stomp session handler in spring boot but after connectiong established it's not called afterConnected() method i can see "In connection" but not "connected" in console and than after few minute console print "failed in transportConnection closed" which is in transport exception.. I am using spring websocket client...

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

@Service
public class MyStompClient extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @EventListener(value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("In connection...");
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        try {
            StompSession stompSession = stompClient
                    .connectAsync("wss://ws.finnhub.io/?token=my_token", this)
                    .get();
            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        System.out.println("After Connected Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("in ex: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("failed in transport"  + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {

    }
}
```

on running application it should be called after connected method

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, and i have a not-solution for you: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31021 
Cite: "Other clients are connecting fine, just not Spring clients after upgrading." Maybe they will fix this, the comment is only 6 hours old. 
Hope that helps.